# Hide Button if TextBox is invalid

Tags: angular, validation

I have a textbox that has an email pattern on it, and I want to hide a span with a (click) if the pattern fails. Here is what I have that I assume should work

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Signup for Mailing List" #userEmail="ngModel" style="width:300px" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required email>
  <span (click)="signup()" class="fa fa-envelope-o" *ngIf="userEmail.touched && !userEmail?.valid" style="position: relative;z-index: 1;cursor:pointer;left: -35px;width: 0; color:gray"></span>
```

Is that *ngIf wrong? The button never shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Signup for Mailing List" 
       #userEmail="ngModel" style="width:300px" 
       name="emails" [(ngModel)]="emails"
       pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required email>
<span (click)="signup()" class="fa fa-envelope-o" 
      *ngIf="userEmail.touched && userEmail?.valid" // remove the !sign 
      style="position: relative;z-index: 1;cursor:pointer;left: -35px;width: 0; color:gray"></span>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.